# How to test https API in siege?

Tags: performance, rest, api, siege

I have developed a REST API which is in the form of

```
https://abc.def.in/appname/data?id=1&un=sha
```

This also heas the jwt token as a http header.

So I wanted to test this api with 1000 users using simultaneously using siege.So I installed siege and tested with

```
siege https://abc.def.in/appname/data?id=1&un=sha
```

But it returned with

```
[error]: Host not found
```

But when I installed I install like below:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
make
make install
```

I installed as in the manual but I don't know why the error host not found is occuring.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this address: https://abc.def.in/appname/data?id=1&un=sha work when you check it with a browser?

Comment: @Picard  Could you help in this question [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794750/error-while-installing-siege)